# Return to WoW - Warlords of Draenor - what to do with old items/pots/tokens?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So after several years, I decided to get back to World of Warcraft with the 6.2 WoD release.

I found my bank and bags are filled with Orgrimmar items, tokens, badges and whole kind of items that aren't effective anymore. Should I simply delete all of them?

Any items worth keeping?

Tokens I refer to are the ones that increase reputation with factions mainly.

Comment: what sorta tokkens/badges are we talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to check the AH if people are buying them and see if you can make a little gold to help you get into the game easier.

Regarding Badges and tokens I'm not sure what you are referring here to... 
Tier tokens might be nice for Transmog for you if you prefer that look.

Old raid currencies and everything got converted to gold awhile back so your not talking about that.

Anything else, unless its still tied to some sorta achievement(which you are interested in) you can just delete.

Also old pots/flasks might be interesting to people that lock their character to a lower level to experience the raids properly at the given level. They cant use the current flask/food so they have to use the stuff from the given expansion.

If none of the above points tell you anything regarding your item, your best bet is to go on [wowhead](http://wowhead.com) and look up if the item is still usefull for something.